# Add link in Magento menu

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am trying to manually add a link in my menu but it won't work. Here is what I tried : I edited navigation/top.phtml in my theme folder but it won't change anything. I also tried to edit navigation/top.phtml in my "base" folder without success. Any idea of the right file I have to edit to get my hand on this menu ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below link will helps you.

http://www.webdosh.net/2011/03/adding-links-to-top-menu-of-magento.html

Comment: This is what I tried, I edited ../mytheme/../top.phtml, but It won't do anything.

Comment: Even if I deactivate cache, it won't work. Navigation menu does not seem to be cached anyway.